# access exported method in mainactivity from other program

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have a Problem with Xamarin Forms. We was writing UI-Tests with the Xamarin.UITest Nuget.
And for this we managed to make a really critical funktion to run. Triggering a Scan from the UI-Test.
(Because we have Android Device with a Hardwarescanner build in and so)

Currently we achieving it like so:

in the Main Activity:

```
 [Export]
 public void TriggerScanEvent(string type, string code) => _receiveScan(type, code);
```

in the UI-Test:

```
 public void TestScan(string codeType, string code)
 {
     app.Invoke("TriggerScanEvent", new object[] { codeType, code });
 }
```

But the Testteam changed and they want to Use Appium instead.
i am pretty shure this has to work also. because the app has functions the requires a scan without a textinput or something else.

i alrteady searched the google oracle but all i found was:

```
android:exported="true"
```

has anyone a really got hint for me?
the most important thing is: is this possible, or do we have to rewrite the app?
Edit: Appium is basically using python and selenium.
so all we have to do, is somehow call the opened fuction from python/selenium